# Analytic isomorphism of affine nonsingular curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

I'm getting confused on an exercise in Appendix B of Hartshorne's *Algebraic Geometry*:

> If two affine nonsingular curves are isomorphic as complex manifolds, then they're isomorphic as algebraic varieties.

I don't know how the affine and nonsingular condition can be used here. Any proof or reference is appreciated.

Comment: @reuns I think the key here is how to show the first statement, since from analytic isomorphism we only know they have same holomorphic/meromorphic functions

Comment: My guesses are that nonsingular is mentioned so one does not have to deal with complex-analytic spaces which aren't manifolds and affine is used to let you worry about just global functions. Curve is very important here, since [there are counterexamples already in dimension 2](https://mathoverflow.net/a/68425).

Answer (score 0):

The field of rational functions are isomorphic as well as the ring of regular functions.

The non-singular requirement is to make sure the ring of regular functions is the same on both side.

An isomorphism of affine variety is the same as an isomorphism of their coordinate ring.

For example $x $ is in $\Bbb{C}[x]$ but not in $\Bbb{C}[x^2,x^3]$ ($\cong \Bbb{C}[y,z]/(y^3-z^2)$ the coordinate ring of $V(y^3-z^2)$) whereas in both case the function field is $\Bbb{C}(x)$ and the underlying complex manifold is $\Bbb{C}$.

Thus there is no affine variety isomorphism $\Bbb{A^1_C} \to V(y^3-z^2)$. This is because $V(y^3-z^2)$ is singular at $(0,0)$.

---

From the isomorphic field of rational functions you can construct a common compact Riemann surface $C$ (isomorphic to a non-singular projective curve) containing both $A,B$,  that $A,B$ are non-singular implies that their coordinate ring is the whole ring of meromorphic functions on $C$ whose poles are located on $C-A,C-B$.

Comment: Can you explain why the field of rational functions are isomorphic? Unlike the projective case, the meromorphic functions on affine curves are not necessary rational.

Comment: They are because an affine curve, with its few singular points removed, is the underlying compact Riemann surface / smooth projective curve minus a few isolated points. At those few points a function $f$ which is rational on $A$ (if it has a pole consider $1/f$) satisfies the conditions of the removable singularities thus is analytic at the corresponding missing point of $B$.

Comment: To understand the idea of missing point you can construct, from the rational function field of $A$, the underlying compact Riemann surface, whose chart around $p$ is given by any rational function $f$ such that $f-f(p)$ has a simple zero at $p$.

Comment: How do you construct this common compact Riemann surface?